# Special characters not showing up in Scribus

Tags: linux, debian, fonts, layout, scribus

Unicode symbol 266D (♭) will not appear in Scribus, whatever the font. Besides, I've made sure already that the symbol I want is contained in the font I am using, here *Times New Roman (Regular)*. The symbol does appear in the Story Editor (Ctrl+T), though. In the actual document, however, it is replaced with a weirdly positioned empty square, as can be seen on the screenshot below. As already mentioned, the problem persists with whatever the font. It also persists regardless of whether the text is placed within a text frame or within a table cell, as is the case in my screenshot.

[image: screenshot of layout]

In case it matters, here's a bit of information on what I'm trying to achieve: I'm trying to make a flashcard set, and will probably be redoing this in the future, so I want to find a way to not have to bother dragging the image of a flat, sharp or natural sign every time I want it to appear on a flashcard.

I'm using Scribus version 1.5.6.1, which was installed using the APT package manager on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (Bullseye), amd64.

Comment: How are you inserting the special characters? [Here](https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Typography) they suggest _The quicker way to insert special glyphs is to hit F12, then type the 4-digit code for the character you want:_  e.g. 266d. In some word and pdf files this problem occurs when you do not embed the (whole) fonts in the document, or when you pass from a system to another. Just some hints...

Comment: (1) What happens when you paste such a character? (2) Does it work to use the menu *Extras > Insert Specials* that allows choosing your character from the entire font set. (3) For music notation try [lilypond](http://lilypond.org/) as explained [here](https://forums.scribus.net/index.php?topic=3346.0).

Comment: Thank you both for your tips. Finally, I figured out why it worked in LibreOffice, and not Scribus. It's because, in LO, the flat symbol was borrowed from another font even when using *Times New Roman*, oddly enough. That's why I thought the flat symbol was included in *Times New Roman*, even though I know see that it's not (in the version I have on my computer, at least). Even though I said that the problem persists with "whatever the font", I jumped too quickly to that conclusion. It does work with *some* fonts (i.e. *DejaVu Sans*). Cheers, and thank you again.

Comment: @GPWR You should post that comment as an answer and check it off as such. That is a very weird combination of reasons for that happening.